# Exit Condition for Knight's Tour Using Depth-First Search

Tags: algorithms, depth-first-search

Suppose I'm using the algorithm below to perform Depth-First Search in a 2d Grid.

It seems like it should be possible to adjust it to perform a Knight's Tour with little change.

For example I would replace

`for each offset in ["up", "down", "left", "right"]`

with

`for each offset in possible Knight moves`.

EDIT: I would also call `dfs()` with `None` as the `goal` argument, or some position which can't be reached.

What I'm confused about is how to return the path when the goal position is undefined.

I thought of checking the length of the path each pass through the `while` loop and returning the path if it is as long as the total number of squares on the board, but I ran into a problem with in my `get_path()` function, as `None` (the return value of `dfs()` when the goal is not found) has no predecessor.

Please could someone explain how my algorithm can be modified to return a full path for a Knight's Tour?

```
function dfs(grid, start, goal)
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push(start)
    discovered = set()
    discovered.add(start)
    predecessors = dict()
    predecessors[start] = None

    while stack not empty:
            current = stack.pop()
            if current == goal:
                    return get_path(predecessors, start, goal)
            for each offset in ["up", "down", "left", "right"]
                    new = current + offset
                    if new not in discovered and new is on board:
                            stack.push(new)
                            discovered.add(new)
                            predecessors[new] = current

    return None

function get_path(predecessors, start, goal):
    current = goal
    path = []
    while current != start:
        path.append(current)
        current_pos = predecessors[current]
    path.append(start)
    path.reverse()
    return path
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be an issue of coding. When performing DFS, either you have found a knight's tour, or your knight is stuck – no further move is possible – in which case you backtrack. In this description there is no "None" whatsoever.

Comment: I would call the dfs function with `None` as the goal argument, or some position which can't be reached. Question edited.

Comment: This is something particular about your implementation of DFS. More generally, DFS is a backtracking algorithm, which for the case of a knight's tour, starts at an empty board, then puts a knight somewhere, then repeatedly tries to extend the tour. Again, in this description I don't see any goal argument or any None. If your code doesn't match this description, then you'll have to change your code.